# Converting from short to unsigned short and preserving the bit pattern confusion

Tags: c, type-conversion, data-conversion, unsigned, signed

I am working on a project where I need to get a range of signed 16-bit ints, negative and positive values,  and send them to a function to analyse during unit tests.

For different reasons, the function only takes an array of unsigned 16-bit ints, so I need to store the signed ints in an unsigned 16-bit integer array and completely preserve the same bit pattern. I am using gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0.

```
unsigned short arr[450];
unsigned short arrIndex = 0;

for (short i = -32768; i < (32767 - 100) ; i = i + 100 )
{
    arr[arrIndex] = i; 

    printf("short value is          : %d\n", i);
    printf("unsigned short value is : %d\n", arr[arrIndex]);
    arrIndex++;
}
```

Even tho i'm telling printf to print signed values, I am surprised to see that the bit patterns are actually different for those values less than zero. The first few values are below:

```
short value is           : -32768
unsigned short value is  : 32768

short value is           : -32668
unsigned short value is  : 32868

short value is           : -32568
unsigned short value is  : 32968
```

What is happening here, and how would I preserve the bit pattern for the values of i below zero?

Comment: By "signed 16-bit ints" do you actually mean "signed 16-bit integers" and your `int` is 32-bit not 16-bit?

Comment: @WeatherVane That's what I mean, by giving the format specifier %d.. I was expecting to see negative values

Comment: @WeatherVane If I changed my comments to say "shorts" instead of "ints", would you be happier?

Comment: You need to make it clear what `%d` is expecting and what you mean by "ints". The smallest `int` size is 16 bits. Integer arguments for a variadic function that are smaller than the native `int` will be promoted to `int` in accordance with the usual integer promotion rules. If your `int ` is 32 bits it can handle the entire range of `signed short` and `unsigned short`.

Comment: Did you mean to increment `arrIndex` at the end of that loop? Otherwise, you're reading the wrong value back.

Comment: When I use %X, for the first value, the short value is FFFF8000 hex and the unsigned short value is 8000 hex. Both types have the same size, so i'm a bit confused by this.

Comment: ...the compiler does not adjust the promotion to suit the format specifier. (It only issues warning messages about type compatibility out of kindness).

Comment: @templatetypedef You are right. A typo. Fixed it, thanks

Comment: `%X` interprets whatever data you pass as `unsigned` and `printf` does not know or care how you defined the value that was passed to it. It sees the format specifier at run-time and interprets the bytes your provide accordingly. If you mis-match the types, for example pass a `double` for `%X` it blindly looks at 4 bytes and does what it is told.

Comment: The key is to understand the bits stored in memory do not change regardless of whether it is a signed or unsigned value of the same size. Considering the bits as either signed or unsigned provide a different view of the same bits. When viewed as signed, if bit-15 is `1`, the value is a treated as negative (two-compilent on most systems). When viewed as unsigned there is no special treatment. So what is in memory doesn't change -- only the way you interpret the bits changes.

Comment: @WeatherVane Re: "pass a double for %X it blindly looks at 4 bytes " --> note that passing integer values vs FP ones may involve different schemes (like using a FP reg. vs. stack).  The 4 bytes `"%X"` seeks may address invalid memory. IAC, that is UB.

Comment: @chux good point. I always overlook different ways of parameter passing.

Answer (score 3):

> how would I preserve the bit pattern for the values of `i` below zero?

With the very common 2's complement encoding the following is sufficient.

```
unsigned short us = (unsigned short) some_signed_short;
```

BITD day with ones' complement and sign-magnitude, this was not sufficient and code would use a `union` of `short` and `unsigned short`.

Yet by virtue of how a negative value 2's complement is converted to *unsigned*, the bit pattern is preserved for same sized types.

---

> the bit patterns are actually different for those values less than zero.

The bit patterns are the same. They went through different conversion paths to get printed and so have different text output.

---

When printing `short, unsigned short`, best to use a h printf modifier.

```
//printf("short value is          : %d\n", i);
//printf("unsigned short value is : %d\n", arr[arrIndex]);
printf("short value is          : %hd\n", i);
printf("unsigned short value is : %hu\n", arr[arrIndex]);
```

Comment: However, it's confusing. My third value that I printed out : short value is           : -32568
unsigned short value is  : 32968 . Shouldn't -32568 become 32568 if using 2's complement , the negative value becomes the same value positive?

Comment: No.  With printing `short -32568`, the value was converted to an `int` and printed as `-32568`. With printing `unsigned short 32968`, the value was converted to an `int` and printed as `32968`.  The key here is in printing, as ... arguments to `printf()`, the value was converted to `int` first and then printed.  On your system `int` range  is more than `short` and `unsigned short` and so it preserved the original value.

Comment: Shouldn't getting the 2's complement of a number, give the same number but opposite sign?

Comment: @Engineer999 Please explain in detail what you mean by _getting_.

Comment: @Engineer999 When a negative `short` value is converted to an `unsigned short`, arithmetically `USHRT_MAX + 1` is added (per C conversion rules) and the sum is saved.  A side effect of this is that the bit pattern does not change as the sign bit in `short` is the -32768 place and the same bit in `unsigned short` is  +32768 place.  A change of `USHRT_MAX + 1`.

Comment: @Engineer999 I think you might want to read about [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Sign_extension) in twos complement.

Comment: I understand sign extension , but perhaps don't know what you're trying to explain. "With the very common 2's complement encoding the following is sufficient....  unsigned short us = (unsigned short) some_signed_short" . So by doing this, if the  some_signed_short value is negative, the us variable should get the positive value . so -3000, will be converted to 3000  ?

Comment: @Engineer999 No.  The `unsigned short`  value will be `negative_signed_short_value + USHRT_MAX + 1` or `negative_signed_short_value + 65536` or in this case `-3000 + 65536 = 62536`.  The same bit pattern.  No sign extension involved.

Answer (score 2):

In C, if you call a variadic function and pass in an integral type of any sort, the language will automatically promote it to a signed or unsigned `int` of the same type. When you then print things out using the `%d` modifier, you're seeing the promoted int as a result.

For example, when you call

```
printf("short value is          : %d\n", i);
```

The (negative) value of `i` is getting promoted to a `signed int` with the same value, which is why it prints out as negative. When you then call

```
printf("unsigned short value is : %d\n", arr[arrIndex]);
```

The (unsigned) value of `arr[arrIndex]` gets promoted to an `unsigned int`, which is why you see the positive value displayed.

To fix this, change your `printf` so that you tell the compiler to display the results specifically as `short` variables:

```
printf("short value is          : %hd\n", i);
printf("unsigned short value is : %hd\n", arr[arrIndex]);
```

Now, you'll see the values agreeing.

Comment: "value of arr[arrIndex] gets promoted to an unsigned int" --> true with 16-bit `int/unsigned`.  Value of `arr[arrIndex]` gets promoted to an `int` on 32 bit ones.

Answer (score 2):

The values are being copied correctly. Let's look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printit(char *name, short int val)
  {
  printf("%s  %hd  %hu  0x%hX\n", name, val, val, val);
  }

int main()
  {
  short int v1 = 0x8000;
  short int v2 = 0x8064;
  short int v3 = 0x80C8;

  printit("v1", v1);
  printit("v2", v2);
  printit("v3", v3);
  }
```

Here I'm created four signed short variables, and setting them to bit patterns. Forget "positive" and "negative" for a moment - I'm just shoving a bit pattern into those variables. In the subroutine `printit` those values are printed as signed decimal, unsigned decimal, and hex (to verify it's all the same bit pattern). Now, look at the results:

```
v1  -32768  32768  0x8000
v2  -32668  32868  0x8064
v3  -32568  32968  0x80C8
```

Now you can see that I just copied the values you used (-32768, -32668, and -32568) and assigned them to the variables. The only difference is that I converted them to hexadecimal first. Same bit pattern. Same results. But, except in a few rare cases, the signed decimal value interpretation of a bit pattern where the decimal value is negative is NOT the same as the unsigned decimal interpretation of a bit pattern. I suggest reading up on [One's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) for binary numbers, and [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of negative binary numbers.

Comment: Bob `short int v1 = 0x8000;` starts off the _implmention defined behavior_ (usually benign) as `0x8000` is outside the `short` range.  `short int v1 = -32768;` or `= -0x8000`, although less illustrative, do not have that issue.

Answer (score 1):

The data is copied correctly, bit-by-bit as you wanted. It's the just the printing that displays it as a signed value because `arr` is declared as an array of unsigned values.

`%d` prints the data passed as `int`s (by standard definition? not sure), which on common platforms is 4-bytes. The argument passed to `printf` is upgraded to an `int` before being printed, which, depending on whether the argument in question is signed or not, will require sign-extension or not.

When printing `i`, which is a signed value, the value will be sign-extended before being printed. For example, if `i` is `-1` (which, is represented as `0xFFFF` on a 2-byte signed value using two's complement), then `i` will be upgraded as the `int` value `0xFFFFFFFF` (which also is `-1`, but represented with four bytes).

However, if `i` is equal to `-1`, then, when doing `arr[arrIndex] = i`, `arr[arrIndex]` will indeed be set to `0xFFFF`, copied bit-by-bit as you wanted. However, since `arr[arrIndex]` is unsigned, in the world of the unsigned, `0xFFFF` represents `65535`. Then, when the time comes to print `arr[arrIndex]`, since `arr[arrIndex]` is unsigned, the value will *not* be sign-extended, since it is an unsigned value. `0xFFFF` would therefore be upgraded to `0x0000FFFF`, which is equal to `65535`, and printed as such.

We can verify this by forcing `arr` to be considered signed before being printed. That way, `arr` will be treated the same way `i` is treated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    unsigned short arr[450];
    unsigned short arrIndex = 0;

    for (signed short i = -32768; i < (32767 - 100) ; i = i + 100 )
    {
        arr[arrIndex] = i;
        printf("short value is          : %d\n", i);
        printf("unsigned short value is : %d\n", ((signed short*)arr)[arrIndex]);
        arrIndex++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
short value is          : -32768
unsigned short value is : -32768
short value is          : -32668
unsigned short value is : -32668
short value is          : -32568
unsigned short value is : -32568
short value is          : -32468
unsigned short value is : -32468
short value is          : -32368
unsigned short value is : -32368
short value is          : -32268
unsigned short value is : -32268
short value is          : -32168
unsigned short value is : -32168
```

Or, we could directly declare `arr` as an array of signed values to achieve the same result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    signed short arr[450];
    unsigned short arrIndex = 0;

    for (signed short i = -32768; i < (32767 - 100) ; i = i + 100 )
    {
        arr[arrIndex] = i;
        printf("short value is          : %d\n", i);
        printf("unsigned short value is : %d\n", arr[arrIndex]);
        arrIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the `for` loop limits, as if you go from `-32768` to `<(32767-100)` in leaps of **100** values, you fill **655** array elements, and you have only declared **450**.

Also, to print an `unsigned short` value, you need to use `%u` (or the equivalent `%hu`, as `short`s are converted to `int` for `printf()` usage) format specifier.

Use this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        short i;
        for (i = -32768; i < (32767 - 100); i += 100) {
                unsigned short j = i;
                printf("Signed  : %d\n", i);
                printf("Unsigned: %u\n", j);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

It will produce:

```
$ a.out
Signed  : -32768
Unsigned: 32768
Signed  : -32668
Unsigned: 32868
Signed  : -32568
Unsigned: 32968
Signed  : -32468
...
Signed  : -268
Unsigned: 65268
Signed  : -168
Unsigned: 65368
Signed  : -68
Unsigned: 65468
Signed  : 32
Unsigned: 32
Signed  : 132
Unsigned: 132
...
Signed  : 32432
Unsigned: 32432
Signed  : 32532
Unsigned: 32532
Signed  : 32632
Unsigned: 32632
$ _
```